# js confirm refreshes page if cancelled

Tags: javascript

So I have a form that when submitted requires confirmation. I am using Javascript confirm to prompt for this. However, I do not want it to refresh if someone hits cancel. I thought putting an empty else statement would do so, however it appears I was wrong.

Not sure what I need to be doing to make sure it does NOT refresh if someone presses cancel on the popup.

#### the JS confirm code

```
function postConfirm() {
   if (confirm('You will not have another chance after submitting to view your post. Please make sure it is exactly how you want it before continuing. ')) {
       yourformelement.submit();
   } else {

   }
}
```

#### the form that uses this JS function (if needed)

```
<div id="uploadForm">
        <center>
          <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="functions/post_upload.php" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="99999999" />
            <div><textarea id="text" cols="70" rows="15" name="entry"></textarea></div>
            <p> Attach an image to this memory!</p>
            <input name="userfile" type="file"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="blueButton" onclick="postConfirm()"/></div>
          </form></center>
        </div>
```

Comment: Where is `yourformelement` refer?

Comment: tbh its been 6 years, I do not remember haha

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change:

```
onclick="postConfirm()"
```

to

```
onclick="return postConfirm()"
```

and in your function, make the else:

```
else {
    return false;
   }
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/EChQF/)**

Answer (score 3):

try adding

```
return false;
```

to the else part of your if statement.

**Edit:**

Also modify your call to the function so that the **return false is passed back to the submit action** (which is fired when the button is clicked).

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="blueButton" onclick="return postConfirm()"/></div>
```

Comment: `return false;` still refreshes the page if I press cancel.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent form submission using the `preventDefault()` method of event object and manually submit the form upon confirmation using the `submit()` method of form elements.

Change your `HTML` to:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="blueButton" onclick="postConfirm(event)"/></div>

function postConfirm(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if(confirm('You will not have another chance after submitting to view your post. Please make sure it is exactly how you want it before continuing. ')) 
   yourformelement.submit();
}
```

---

However, it is better to avoid inline javascript since it is considered a bad practice. Instead you can do:

```
var button = document.getElementsByClassName("blueButton")[0];
button.addEventListener("click",function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if(confirm('You will not have another chance after submitting to view your post. Please make sure it is exactly how you want it before continuing. ')) 
   yourformelement.submit();
});
```

Answer (score -2):

try

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" class="blueButton" onclick="postConfirm()"/></div>
```

instead of

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="blueButton" onclick="postConfirm()"/></div>
```